# reduce from angular 6 to angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install, ng-build

I wish to reduce down from angular 6 to angular 4. Angular 6 has been more of a headache then what its worth.

I started to notice that when I ran `ng serve` I would get an accurate version of my site but when I ran `ng build` I would get a version several commits behind.

I attempted many solves over the past few days which no sucess.

I am some what in the dark as to what the correct process is to do this, hence why I think I am still having trouble.

my code is currently in a repo on bitbucket.

I wish to completely remove angular from my system.

`npm uninstall`

Then install

`npm install angular-cli@<correct version number>`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli#updating-angular-cli

then I wish to clone my online repo, and change the `angular-cli.json` file contents to the versions that work with angular 4

then it is my hope, that all will be right and I can go back to coding my project.

Node, npm, the javascript community entirely seems to be this really confusing place where there does not seem to be a lot of cross communication. So all of this is a shot in the dark for me. Some clarification and direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question and elaborate what exactly is not working for you and why you want to downgrade? if you still wish to downgrade, look for 'downgrade Angular 6 to Angular 4\5" and you will get proper results on stackoverflow.

Comment: @monogate I gave the best description I can because I don't know I am at this point throwing a nuke on a ant hill. my question pertains to how to properly reduce from angular 6 to 4. The reason is irrelevant, only because in the scope of my question it is irrelevant.